# How to maintain checkstate of items in Devexpress Virtual Treeview?

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, devexpress, virtualtreeview

I have a Treeview created in virtual mode which have 4 levels of nodes and at the page load the root element and first level elements are loaded and rest will be loaded based on dynamically using `treeFolderList_VirtualModeCreateChildren` event.

**This is what I have so far**

```
protected void treeFolderList_VirtualModeCreateChildren(object source, TreeViewVirtualModeCreateChildrenEventArgs e)
{
    List<TreeViewVirtualNode> children = new List<TreeViewVirtualNode>();


    if (e.NodeName == null)
    {
        AppendChildNode(children, "root", "All Domains", false);
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.NodeName.Contains("root"))
        {
            PopulateChildNodes(false, children);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!(e.NodeName.StartsWith("u_")))
            {
                PopulateUserChildNodes(false, children, GetDomainBase(e.NodeName), e.NodeName);
            }
            else
            {
                TreeViewVirtualNode tvNode = (TreeViewVirtualNode)treeFolderList.Nodes.FindByName(e.NodeName);
                TreeViewVirtualNode tvNodeParent = (TreeViewVirtualNode)tvNode.Parent;
                string tvParentNodeName = tvNodeParent.Name;
                PopulateUserChildNodes(true, children, GetDomainBase(tvParentNodeName), e.NodeName);
            }
        }
    }
    e.Children = children;
}
```

This work as expected and it creates the children elements when expanding nodes respectively. My problem is I have check boxes for each node and I need to be able to save the `Treeview` in a way when I reload/redirect to the page it would reflect the nodes I have selected.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to try to achieve this:

1. Configure [ASPxTreeList.SettingsCookies](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListASPxTreeList_SettingsCookiestopic)  element (probably the easiest solution), in particular the StoreSelection attribute:

   ```
   <dvx:ASPxTreeList ... >
   ...
       <SettingsCookies Enabled="true" StoreSelection="true"  />
   ...
   </dvx:ASPxTreeList>
   ```
2. If SettingsCookies doesn't work try saving and restoring the TreeList layout manually using [ASPxTreeList.ClientLayout](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListASPxTreeList_ClientLayouttopic) event. Define the event handler first:

   ```
   <dvx:ASPxTreeList OnClientLayout="dvxTreeList_ClientLayout"... >
   ...
   </dvx:ASPxTreeList>
   ```

   and follow the example in the doc to handle this event. This way ASPxTreeView  as well as the ASPxGridView provide the node/column format data in the  `e.LayoutData` string which can be saved to DB and then restored back.
3. Store the TreeView selected node keys in Session and restore them using callbacks:

   Example: [ASPxTreeList - How to store the selection between requests](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/T187249)

I personally would not rely on cookies and would try methods #2 and #3 first. #2 has been working nicely for me with ASPxGridView and #3 we use in a complex ASPxTreeView setup which also tracks the selection of hidden nodes.

I hope the examples in the linked docs should be easy enough for you to copy and modify. If not, comment what is not working for you.

HTH

Comment: fantastic mate! worked excellently.Saved the list along with other stuff i wanted to the DB and retrieved it and set the client layout mode is Loading.

Comment: @LandMaster Great! I'm glad you got it working. Thanks for the accept and upvote.